Fourier expansion of periodic Weierstrass Zeta function
I am interested in the quasi-periodic Weierstass Zeta function $\zeta(z; \omega_1, \omega_2)$ where the half-periods are chosen to be $\omega_1 = 1$ $\omega_2 = a e^{i \pi/3}$ ($a = \sqrt{2 \pi}/3^{1/4}$) which has poles on a triangular lattice with a unit cell of area $\pi$ (i.e. lattice sites at $z_{jk} = 2j \omega_1 + 2k \omega_2$). We can then form a periodic function
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = i \zeta(z)^* - i z.
\end{equation*}
Owing to the periodicity, we can expand the real part (or the imaginary part) according to
\begin{equation*}
\Re f(x+iy) = \sum_{b_G} f^R_{b_G} e^{ib_G\cdot (x,y)}
\end{equation*}
where $b_G$ are the reciprocal lattice vectors and $ f^R_{b_G}$ are the Fourier components.
I cannot exactly find these Fourier components for either the real or imaginary parts of $f$, and I also cannot find a particularly stable numerical procedure (even when I'm careful to handle the the $1/z$ pole).
Is there an approach to calculate these Fourier components for both the real and imaginary parts of $f$? This method could also be a stable numerical procedure.
Thanks for any help you can provide!
